# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.parquet. (Reading Parquet file)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

Trying to read a `Parquet` file in PySpark but getting `Py4JJavaError`. I even tried reading it from the `spark-shell` and was able to do so. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong here in terms of the Python APIs that it is working in Scala and not in PySpark;

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test-read").getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.read.parquet("game_logs.parquet")
```

Stack Trace:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>()

~/pyenv/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, *paths)
    301         [('name', 'string'), ('year', 'int'), ('month', 'int'), ('day', 'int')]
    302         """
--> 303         return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
    304 
    305     @ignore_unicode_prefix

~/pyenv/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/pyenv/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/pyenv/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.parquet.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2073)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:611)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:202)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844
```

Enviornment Info:

```
Spark version 2.3.1     
Using Scala version 2.11.8, 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_172
Python 3.6.5
PySpark 2.3.1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong exactly. The `spark-shell` was using `Java 1.8`, but `PySpark` was using `Java 10.1`. There is some issue with Java 1.9/10 and Spark. Changed the default Java version to 1.8.

Comment: How do I check the Java version of spark shell and then change it?

Comment: how to change the pyspark default java version to 1.8

Comment: @saravanansaminathan @Auren `sudo update-alternatives --config java
` use to switch between different java versions installed on your system.

Comment: I was using both mysql and parquet file read, so I suspected the mariadb driver, after that i figured out to use the hdfs:// path

Comment: You can improve this answer by describing how to check the Java versions used by `PySpark` and `spark-shell`.

Comment: pyspark --version and spark-shell --version .

Comment: To find out what version of java you have currently on a mac use this command: java -version. For windows use this: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml

Comment: I was using pyspark==2.3.2/java11 and had same issue. After I switched to java8 it works well. (pyspark==3.3.1 works well with java11)

Answer (score 2):

Spark runs on Java 8/11.

For switching between Java versions, you can add this to your .bashrc/.zshrc file:

```sh
alias j='f(){ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1) };f'
```

Then in your terminal:

```sh
source .zshrc
```

```sh
j 1.8
```

```sh
java -version
```

This will change the version system-wide. If you just want it different for one app you can prepend it with the environment variable JAVA_HOME

```sh
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) jupyter notebook
```

```py
%env JAVA_HOME {path}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java Version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Python Version:

```
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

PySpark Version:

```
3.0.1
(Note: This version is the key)
```

This combination works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your hadoop version matches with spark version, then make a copy of hadoop-common jar into spark jar folder. The hadoop-common must be the same version with hadoop-aws jar, in my case hadoop-aws-3.2.2.jar and hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar.