# conversion of csv file to parquet file using pyspark : Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o347.parquet error

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to convert csv to Parquet. I am using python 3.6 and spark 2.3.1 64 bit. I am not able to find the solution for given trace back.
I am also using 64 bit python.

I have this csv:

```
Corp,Vathanya Beck
Corp,Mario Bazile
Open,Hasom Bennitt-traflet
Open,Jonathon Berry
Corp,Ayinde Amezquita
Corp,Carol Airiofolo
Corp,Wilfredo Brozo
```

I can make csv to parquet using pandas function to_parquet but somehow spark is not working properly. In pandas I have used pyarrow engine for conversion.
I am using following spark code to convert csv to Parquet:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType ,StructField,StringType
SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).appName("BLEH").getOrCreate()
schema = StructType([StructField('type', StringType(), True),
                 StructField('name1', StringType(), True)])


df = sqlContext.read.csv('cv_transactions.csv',schema)
df.show()
```

following is the given output after reading csv in spark dataframe.

```
+----+--------------------+
|type|               name1|
+----+--------------------+
|Corp|       Vathanya Beck|
|Corp|        Mario Bazile|
|Open|Hasom Bennitt-tra...|
|Open|      Jonathon Berry|
|Corp|    Ayinde Amezquita|
|Corp|     Carol Airiofolo|
|Corp|      Wilfredo Brozo|
+----+--------------------+
```

But when I tried to convert to parquet using following code:

```
 df.write.parquet('r.parquet')
```

it gave me following Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o347.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:547)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 25, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Users\rohan_pawar\Documents\parquet\r\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20181214173824_0025_m_000000_0\part-00000-e076c220-6226-4617-abf9-14e7f3a2ce81-c000.snappy.parquet
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:241)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:342)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    ... 8 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Users\rohan_pawar\Documents\parquet\r\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20181214173824_0025_m_000000_0\part-00000-e076c220-6226-4617-abf9-14e7f3a2ce81-c000.snappy.parquet
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:241)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:342)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Please post complete traceback - it is not possible to determine the problem with only the first few lines.

Comment: You do have missing data ? The could be the root cause of the error

Comment: @user10465355 I have updated the full traceback.

Comment: @LaSul I don't find any missing data. did you mean missing data in csv?

Comment: Yup, this happens sometime when you have missing data or NaN into your csv

Comment: @LaSul I checked. I did not find anything.

Comment: Hmmm I was able to run your code successfully too. So, I don't know. To you have write access to the folder you're trying to write to ?

Comment: Yes I do. Actually when it gives error, it also create one folder r.parquet

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run your code just fine. My spark version is as below.

```
$ pyspark --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_191
```

Check out [Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.parquet. (Reading Parquet file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187904/py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o26-parquet-reading-parquet-fil) to see if you have the same problem.
Please check the version of pyspark you are running and update the question with a full stacktrace if the issue persists.